# Using vspace for vertical spacing of text properly

Tags: vertical-alignment

As a rank newbie to LaTeX I have cobbled together 3 or 4 snippets from this site to make a calendar, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
% p is for paragraph length
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{30em}@{}}
  \begin{flushright}\vspace{-.5cm}{\huge February 2021}\end{flushright} \\
  {\huge 15}~\hrulefill \\
  Monday~\dotfill~Presidents' Day\\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  {\huge 16}~\hrulefill \\
  Tuesday~\dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

However I am trying to figure out how to make the vertical space between `February 2021` and the first solid line much smaller than it is (see `vspace` invocation, which does not seem to work.) Ideally, I'd like the solid lines to be aligned at the middle of the day numbers rather than the bottom also.

How do I control margins/padding? Thanks.

Comment: All lists (flushright} add extra space, so it is better to not use them.  Using \hfill instead will align the bottom of the y in February with the top of 15, so it takes negative \vspace to overlap them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
% p is for paragraph length
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{30em}@{}}
\hfill{\huge February 2021}\\[-5pt]
  {\huge 15}\hfill\rule[1ex]{27.5em}{1pt} \\
  Monday~\dotfill~Presidents' Day\\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  {\huge 16}\hfill\rule[1ex]{27.5em}{1pt} \\
  Tuesday~\dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
  \dotfill \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth30em\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\hfill{\huge February 2021}\par\vspace{-.7em}
  {\huge 15}\hfill\rule[1ex]{27em}{1pt} \par
  Monday~\dotfill~Presidents' Day\par
  \dotfill \par
  \dotfill \par
  \dotfill \par
  \dotfill \par\medskip
  {\huge 16}\hfill\rule[1ex]{27.5em}{1pt} \par
  Tuesday~\dotfill \par
  \dotfill \par
  \dotfill \par
  \dotfill \par
  \dotfill \par
\end{document}
```